# Fitting a Multi-Regression Model in Python

Tags: python, regression, training-data, mean-square-error

I am very new to coding and am in the learning phase. I am using `numpy` & `pandas`. I have come across an exercise that needs more help understanding it.

The Data includes 3 predictors (`'x1'` , `'x2'` , `'x3'`) and one target (`'Target'`).

The question I am stuck at;

How do you create different multi-predictor models?

I need to create a list of lists of all unique predictor combinations to fit the curve.

```
# Create a list of lists of all unique predictor combinations to fit the curve
cols = df.drop(['Target'],axis=1)

# Loop over all the predictor combinations 
for i in cols:
    x = cols[i]
    y = df['Target']
```

Comment: Just for clarification: As one of the combinations you want to fit a regression with 'x1' as target and 'x2', 'x3' and 'Target' as predictors?

Comment: Jan, `Target` is still in `df` so there should be no error. `df.drop` is `inplace=False` by default, and in this code the result is assigned to `cols`, not `df`.

Comment: Sia, have you looked at scikit-learn or statsmodels? I suggest you look at those as a starting point.

Comment: i have three predictor variables ('x1' , 'x2' , 'x3') and one response variable ('Target')